# Capturing double click event on a defined layer using OpenLayers.js

Tags: java, javascript, openlayers

A friend of mine is trying to capture the Double Click event using open layers plugin for a certain defined layer on the image.

I would appreciate any insight you can give me.

Thank you.

Comment: As extra info, the OpenLayers.js version in use is 3.0. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This post showed us the way to do it:

http://petrovicslaszlo.com/2013/02/26/openlayers-select-feature-with-double-click/

Comment: Not a helpful answer, link is dead.

Comment: @Superdrac, Maybe this is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370963/way-to-attach-click-and-double-click-events-succesfully-using-raphael-js-openlay

Comment: @CoderRoller unfortunately no.. But i find another way to make what i wanted.