# Way to attach click and double click events succesfully using raphael.js/openlayers.js libraries

Tags: javascript, raphael, openlayers

A friend of mine is having some issues while trying to attach click and double click events simultaneously to do different things each own for a certain layer. He is trying to do it with raphael.js and openlayers.js libraries with no success. We did some research and the solutions on this post: [on click stopped by doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530326/on-click-stopped-by-doubleclick) aren't working completely.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/DAxZA/178/)**:

```
var paper = Raphael('area', 300, 300);

var r = paper.rect(100, 100, 70, 35, 5).attr({fill: 'red'});

r.click(function() {
    this.animate({fill: 'blue'}, 200);
});

r.dblclick(function() {
    this.animate({fill: 'green'}, 200);
});
```